# how to delete a record using apex:outputLink

Tags: apex, visualforce, delete

I was creating a custom output link to delete related record from viusal force page.

```
 <apex:outputLink onClick="return confirmDelete()" value="/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp">Del
       <apex:param name="Id" value="{!id}"/>
     <apex:param name="delID" value="{!o.Id}"/>
     <apex:param name="retURL" value="/apex/CustomTicketsave?id={!id}"/>
       </apex:outputLink>
```

but i was getting error as

```
     The attempted delete was invalid for your session. Please confirm your delete.
```

can some one suggest me how to over come this

[image]

Comment: I just deleted my answer as I just realized my answer used commandlink instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete a record then use URLFOR instead of statically giving url for your destination.
You can achieve it in a much simpler way. Use this code:-

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.delete, account.id)}" onclick="return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</apex:outputLink>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi @Vivek
Any idea how to stop this method from redirecting the page?

Comment: @SamCousins same problem coming in my page also...how did you rectify that?

Comment: Please add 'return false' in onclick attribute, that will prevent redirecting.